# How to add a hash character (#) to a qmake variable

Tags: qmake

I want to write a configuration file with `qmake` that `#define`s a few values. But I cannot simply create variables that contain the hash or pound character (`#`). Nonworking example:

```
lines = "/* Autogenerated: do not edit */"
if(foo): lines += "#define MYLIB_WITH_FOO 1"
else:    lines += "#define MYLIB_WITH_FOO 0"
write_file(config.h, lines)
```

The hash starts a comment (inside the string!), so this won't work. How to generate the proper `#define`s for `write_file` under `qmake`?

Comment: In my opinion, you ask the wrong question. You should have asked: How I can generate a "config.h" header using Qmake, like with autotools or CMake? If you see my answer, there is no need to worry about hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a predefined variable called `LITERAL_HASH` specially created to deal with this problem.

If this name seems too long you can create one of your own:

```
H = $$LITERAL_HASH
lines = "/* Autogenerated: do not edit */"
if(foo): lines += "$${H}define MYLIB_WITH_FOO 1"
else:    lines += "$${H}define MYLIB_WITH_FOO 0"
write_file(config.h, lines)
```

Comment: I cannot believe I spent hours trying to "fix" something that already has a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `$$system()` to create the hash character. This example works for me under Windows and Linux:

```
pound = $$system(printf $$system_quote(\43))
if(foo): lines += "$${pound}define MYLIB_WITH_FOO 1"
else:    lines += "$${pound}define MYLIB_WITH_FOO 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usual on a C or C++ application sources to include a "config.h" header, that is generated by the buildsystem from a template (for instance "config.h.in"). This is available using autotools, and also CMake - see: [configure_file()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html). But what about Qmake?

Here is an alternative using [QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES](https://martin.rpdev.net/2017/05/10/creating-config-header-files-using-qmake.html). [Another reference](https://wiki.qt.io/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir).

test.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT = core
CONFIG += cmdline c++11
VERSION = 1.2.3
FOO = 1
QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES = config.h.in
SOURCES += main.cpp
DISTFILES += config.h.in
```

config.h.in

```
/* Autogenerated: do not edit */
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define MYLIB_VERSION '"$$VERSION"'
#define MYLIB_BANNER '"Project version $$VERSION created with Qt $$QT_VERSION"'
#define MYLIB_WITH_FOO $$FOO

#endif // CONFIG_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << MYLIB_BANNER;
    if (MYLIB_WITH_FOO) {
        qDebug() << "Foo included!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Project version 1.2.3 created with Qt 5.12.5
>
> Foo included!